# How do I force lowercase on an input field?

Tags: javascript, lowercase

I have an input field the client wants to be lowercase only. So the output also generates the input as lowercase.

This is what I currently have and it isn't working.

```
<script>
function toLowerCase(email) {
    strInput.value=strInput.value.toLowerCase();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't force user to enter only lowercase letters, convert the string to lowercase when you're using it

Comment: Bind it to the keypress event handler.

Comment: How isn't it working? Do you get errors? How are you calling the function? What does the HTML look like? Where are you actually using the `email` parameter you pass into the function?

Comment: `style="text-transform: lowercase"`

Comment: @CodeiSir That only changes the styling, not the actual value.

Comment: @j08691 yes, thats why it's only a comment, for creative input ;) I added an answer, that does convert it to real LowerCase

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 11):

You can enforce `text-transform: lowercase;` as style for the input

```html
<input type="text" style="text-transform: lowercase">
```

Comment: I dont know why this was down voted. Its a fully valid solution for the UI. It prevents the uppercase-to-lowercase flash on keyup. A dev just need to ensure the value is set to lower case when it is used.

Comment: possibly cos when submitted the characters are still upper case `username: AdmIni22` that was shown all in lower case on UI but upon submission it was still picked up as put in so a solution if u wish to confuse yourself even more :)

Answer (score 7):

Use `oninput`:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0] // just your input element

input.oninput = function() {
  input.value = input.value.toLowerCase()
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: The problem with this is if you need to go back and edit something. The caret moves repeatedly to the end of the input.

Comment: the correct code is `input.oninput = function(event) { event.target.value = event.target.value.toLowerCase() }` (with proper null-checking)

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS3 property instead.

```
text-transform: lowercase;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ho8zcw68/

Comment: This only changes the styling of the input text, not the actual value.

Comment: You can change by your self later by value.toLowerCase()

Comment: How does that help the OP who already has `toLowerCase` in their question?

Comment: Good!!
Simple and worked correctly

Answer (score 2):

Use patterns:

```
<input pattern="[a-z0-9]+" title="Only lowercase / numbers allowed" />
```

Comment: It would be a shame to blame the user for entering uppercase when you can automatically convert them to lowercase instead.

Comment: You should mention that [some browsers won't support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern)